# How do you improve this

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

This script I made (I'm very new to Python and programming in general) is used to go through a CSV, [see my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58222415/nullify-the-matched-string-contained-in-one-data-frame-column-if-that-is-a-match). I made it to work but is a very rudimentary script that I also need the CSV to have exactly 3 columns or then it does not work, also I have a problem when the column of the CSV is '0' it matches the string I want to delete and delete only the '0' and I don't want that to happen.

Also, any kind of improvements or added functionalities that I can add would be welcome. I'd like to make my code more "solid" overall.

My code is the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# ruta de la carpeta donde esta el archivo
path = "C:\\trabajos\\Schweppes\\"
# nombre del archivo csv
df = pd.read_csv(path + "csv_schewepps.csv", sep=";", encoding = 'utf8')

# ruta y nombre del archivo
archivo = open("C:\\trabajos\\Schweppes\\csv_schewepps.csv", 'r+', errors = 
'ignore', encoding = 'utf8')
# ruta y nombre de un archivo nuevo que se creara
resultado = open("C:\\trabajos\\Schweppes\\csv_schewepps1.csv", 'w', errors 
= 'ignore', encoding = 'utf8')

lista_cp = []
for x in range(-1, len(df.index)):
    lista_cp.append(np.str(df.iloc[x, 1]))

lista_ln = []
for linea in archivo:
    lista_ln.append(linea)

for i in range(0, (len(df.index) + 1)):
    if lista_ln[i].count(lista_cp[i]) > 1:
        nuevo = lista_ln[i].replace(lista_cp[i], "")
        resultado.write(nuevo)
    else:
        resultado.write(lista_ln[i])

# aqui pones el archivo resultado que te ha salido antes
# sino se ejecuta todo de golpe, se ejecuta hasta la linea 29 y se ejecuta 
esta parte
df_2 = pd.read_csv(path + "csv_schewepps1.csv", sep=";")

df_2['cod_postal'] = df['cod_postal']

# el resultado lo crea en un nuevo csv. Este es el resultado final
df_2.to_csv(r"C:\\trabajos\\Schweppes\\csv_schewepps_fin.csv", index=None, 
header=True, sep=";")

archivo.close()
resultado.close()
print ("Fin del script")
```

Comment: For improvements, refer here http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions where you can use list comprehension instead of using a `for` loop to append a list.

Comment: You need to post code that other people can run, otherwise it's very hard to help you. What does your data look like? Suggestions meanwhile: just use `pandas` to write your CSVs, use `with` when you open a file.